# ftp user in cisco nexus 5010 switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, tftp, backups

How to create a ftp user in cisco nexus 5010 switch to archive for autobackup.

Below command is working for normal switches like cisco c3850 but not for Nexus switches. Please advise

```
#FTP Local User
wanftp

#FTP Local Password
v7V5gt5jN3U#
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to Goole the answer in less time than it took for you to write the question:

```
Configure the FTP username and password.

CE_2#config terminal
CE_2(config)#ip ftp username cisco
CE_2(config)#ip ftp password cisco123
CE_2(config)#end
CE_2#
```

From [Back up and Restore Configuration Files](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-122-mainline/46741-backup-config.html#ftp)

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks but that is not working for Nexus switches. It is only working for normal switches like cisco c3850 etc

Comment: Do you need to enable the feature?

Comment: Yes but not sure how to

Comment: Auto backup will require the use of the scheduler: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/5_x/nx-os/system_management/configuration/guide/sm_nx_os_cg/sm_8scheduler.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron, can you please help me for CISCO ASA too as "ip ftp username cisco" command not getting recognized for CISCO ASA. Can we use scheduler for ASA as well.

Comment: I'm sure you can Google just as well as I can.